# Axios interceptor onRejected is not repeating a request

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I use my own interceptor to check if a request is rejected because of token expiry.

After refreshing the token. the original request is supposed to be repeated. However, the following code does not seem to take effect:

```js
return axios.request(attachHeaders(originalRequest));
```

```js
const baseAxios = axios.create();

baseAxios.defaults.baseURL = baseHttpUrl;

const attachHeaders = (request: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosRequestConfig => {
  const accessToken = get(auth).access
  if (accessToken) {
    request.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
  }
  return request
}

baseAxios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  async (error) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;

    //check if the request was not cancelled
    if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
    //check if the error is not related to token expiry
    if (error.response.status !== 401 && error.response.data?.detail !== "expired_token") {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }

    //try to refresh the access_token
    if (await auth.refreshAccessToken()) {
      console.log("request again after token refresh")
      // I get the above log, but the line below does not seem to execute!
      console.log(attachHeaders(originalRequest))//see below
      return axios.request(attachHeaders(originalRequest));
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
)
```

Axios version: 1.1.3.

`console.log(attachHeaders(originalRequest))`

```json
{
    "transitional": {
        "silentJSONParsing": true,
        "forcedJSONParsing": true,
        "clarifyTimeoutError": false
    },
    "transformRequest": [
        null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
        null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "env": {},
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Authorization": "Bearer ACCES_TOKEN_STRING"
    },
    "baseURL": "http://localhost:1000",
    "method": "get",
    "url": "users/1"
}
```

other attempts without success:

```js
return auth.refreshAccessToken().then(async (ok) => {
      if (ok) {
        console.log("request again after token refresh") //gets logged
        return await axios(attachHeaders(originalRequest)) //nothing happens
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    })
```

```js
return auth.refreshAccessToken().then((ok) => {
      if (ok) {
        console.log("request again after token refresh") //gets logged
        return axios(attachHeaders(originalRequest)) //nothing happens
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    })
```

Comment: Did you try to use `return axios.post(attachHeaders(originalRequest)).then(...);` instead?

Comment: I cannot stick to one method `post`. Every request is different.

Comment: Could you check what your `attachHeaders` console logs when it is being called from the failed response? Does it actually attach the headers and return the request correctly?

Comment: @brance I added the console log in the question.

Comment: The only thing I found now is this https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1902#issuecomment-447419559, so maybe try to change your implementation to `await auth.refreshAccessToken().then(...)`. Hope it helps!

Comment: @brance thank you. I tried these. I updated the question. Unfortunately still does not reattempt the original request.

Comment: @brance Thank you for helping out. I figured the issue. See the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently to repeat a request with a previous request's config `AxiosRequestConfig`. The config has to be cloned. A modified config object cannot be used again.
The wrong way:

```js
const attachHeaders = (request: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosRequestConfig => {
  const accessToken = get(auth).access
  if (accessToken) {
    request.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
  }
  return request
}
```

The correct way:

```js
const attachHeaders = (request: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosRequestConfig => {
  const accessToken = get(auth).access
  if (accessToken) {
    return { ...request, headers: { ...request.headers, ["Authorization"]: `Bearer ${accessToken}` } };
  }
  return request
}
```